# how to make a loop in a jenkins pipeline script interruptible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

One of my pipelines needs to wait for an external event to happen before it can continue. I tried using waitUntil, but it completely locked on me without any error (the pipeline would block and not move again). So I moved to a while(...) with a sleep inside.

However, I now have the impression that this while loop cannot be interrupted. Would there be a way to declare a synchronization point for Jenkins, that it can interrupt the whole pipeline ?

Comment: Could you paste your logic for the waitUntil?  The last time I tried it, the waitUntil function worked as expected and was able to be interrupted by things such as aborting the build.  Perhaps you have an infinite loop inside the waitUntil causing the blockage?  A while loop would create a scenario where you couldn't abort and had to forcefully kill the build.

Comment: I don't use waitUntil anymore. I do what is essentially a `while(true) { }`, but call sleep within it, which I assumed would be a synchronization point.